# MySQL Relationships & Joins

Tags: mysql, database, relational-database, innodb

In a MySQL database where there are relationships between tables and the primary key of one table is stored as a foreign key in a second table, is there still a need to perform a join?

If there is, what is the point on declaring the relationship? I'd take a stab in the dark and say it's something to do with the indexing or related tables can find related records much faster? I've tried Googleing this, but can't seem to find much. I'm sure there is loads out there on this, but I don't know the keywords to search for.

Here is an example of table 1 and table 2:

```
------------------- Table 1 ----------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `db_hint`.`user` (
`id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`fb_id` INT NOT NULL,
`last_logged_in` DATETIME NULL,
`permissions` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
INDEX `permissions_id_idx` (`permissions` ASC),
CONSTRAINT `permissions_id`
FOREIGN KEY (`permissions`)
REFERENCES `db_hint`.`permissions` (`id`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;

----------------- Table 2 ----------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `db_hint`.`user_stat` (
`id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`user_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
INDEX `user_id_idx3` (`user_id` ASC),
CONSTRAINT `user_id`
FOREIGN KEY (`user_id`)
REFERENCES `db_hint`.`user` (`id`)
ON DELETE NO ACTION
ON UPDATE NO ACTION)
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

When performing any kind of join, does the InnoDB engine use the relationship in any way? Thanks.

Comment: Foreign keys can also slow down performance depending if you have alot of updates/deletes tied to a foreign key. If your consintency is good you can simply create a field with same datatype and put a regular index on it.

Answer (score 2):

The point of declaring the foreign key is to enforce data consistency. 
You will still need the JOIN in order to get desired data. 
In MySQL foreign keys will improve performance, but don't expect much comparable to indexes.

Comment: `FOREIGN KEYs` have zero impact on `SELECTs`.  They slow down `INSERTs` in order to check for consistency.

Comment: OP is an abject novice.  It may help to explain what Data Integrity between the referencing and referenced tables actually means; why it is essential for a database; what occurs if one does not hve it..

Answer (score 0):

To do a query involving two tables, you need `JOIN ... ON ...` to say how they are related.  `FOREIGN KEYs` are *not* involved in a `SELECT` and has zero impact on performance of `SELECT`.  You do not "have to have" `FOREIGN KEYs` to perform `SELECTs`.

A `FOREIGN KEY` is used during `INSERTs` (and other writes) to verify that a subsequent `JOIN` will actually find something in the other table.  It is an overhead during the write -- the `INSERT` actively checks (via an index) that the referenced table has the indicated row.

`FOREIGN KEYs` *may* also do a cascading operation.  For example, a `DELETE` can cause another `DELETE` to happen.  I prefer to such take control in my application code.